# C++ variadic templates and implicit conversions

Tags: c++, templates, variadic-templates, implicit-conversion

I'm trying to figure out how C++ compilers resolve implicit conversions when a variadic template constructor and a conversion operator exist. Here is a minimal example to illustrate:

When I write:

```
#include <iostream>

class A {
public:
    A () {}

    template<typename...tTypes> A (tTypes...pArgs) {
        std::cout << __PRETTY_FUNCTION__ << std::endl;
    }
};

class B {
public:
    operator A () const {
        std::cout << __PRETTY_FUNCTION__ << std::endl;
        return A();
    }
};

int main() {
    B b;
    A a = b;
}
```

When running I get this output: `B::operator A() const`. So it is using the conversion operator (as I expected). Live example at http://ideone.com/ZZ2uBz

But when `A` is a template the outcome is different:

```
#include <iostream>

template<typename tType>
class A {
public:
    A () {}

    template<typename...tTypes> A (tTypes...pArgs) {
        std::cout << __PRETTY_FUNCTION__ << std::endl;
    }
};

class B {
public:
    template<typename tType>
    operator A<tType> () const {
        std::cout << __PRETTY_FUNCTION__ << std::endl;
        return A<tType>();
    }
};

int main() {
    B b;
    A<float> a = b;
}
```

When running this programm I get this ouput: `A<tType>::A(tTypes ...) [with tTypes = {B}; tType = float]`. So it is using the variadic constructor of `A` instead of the conversion operator in `B`. Live example at http://ideone.com/u9Rxuh

Can someone explain to me why the difference? Shouldn't the conversion operator have precedence over the constructor?

I know I could call the conversion operator explicitly (`A<float> a = b.operator A<float>();`) but that's not what I want.

Comment: I suspect conversion is ambiguous. Actually clang [rejects it](http://melpon.org/wandbox/permlink/Ri8MQBlVHzUvJcHv). Likely a bug of GCC (?).

Comment: You are right other compilers consider the conversion as ambiguous (which in my opinion is much better than choosing one arbitrarily). Do you know of a way to disambiguate this without having to use explicit conversion ?

Comment: [Use explicit constructor](http://melpon.org/wandbox/permlink/lm2ixqVI22j9ze2s) instead. I'm putting this information in an answer. Give me a couple of minutes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems to me that the conversion is ambiguous and the other compilers fail as expected (or at least, that was my expectation). See as an example the result of using [clang](http://melpon.org/wandbox/permlink/Ri8MQBlVHzUvJcHv).

To disambiguate it, you can either make the constructor or the conversion operator explicit.
As an example, use this:

```
template<typename tType>
class A {
public:
    A () {}

    template<typename...tTypes> explicit A (tTypes...pArgs) { /* ... */ }
};
```

Or this:

```
class B {
public:
    template<typename tType>
    explicit operator A<tType> () const { return A<tType>(); }
};
```